# Grid 4 to 3 to 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a grid using Bootstrap 3, and each cell will have this content

```
<a href="/venue/{$venue.urlname}/">
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <img alt="{$venue.name}" src="/files/sivticketsvenues/36/QRbDeQYa_full.jpg" style="width: 50%;" />
        <p style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:#000;color:#FFF;opacity:0.75;padding:10px;">{$venue.name}</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

What would be the correct columns for this? I tried

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
```

Which worked for 4 and 2, but for 3 columns it layed it out like

```
1 2 3
4
5 6 7
8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add all in the same row, like:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">4</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**update**

The above layout will break when your columns don't have the same height. Or more specific when one is taller than the next one in the row. For example give your second column in first row a height of 100px will give you:

[image]

To fix this you have to apply the [Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets). Doing this the above will become:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;height:100px;">2</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">3</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:green;">4</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-lg"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;height:100px;">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">2</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="background-color:green;">4</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-lg"></div>
</div>
</div>
```